# Number of parameter of a quadric

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-module

Suppose for example that $S$ is an algebraic complex surface contained in $\mathbb{P}^6$. $S$ is the complete intersection of four quadrics in the six dimensional projective space.
If i take a quadric is it true that the parameter space of that choice is $\binom{6+2}{2}-1$ ?

If i take $S$ as above what is the dimension of the parameter space for that choice?

Comment: A quadric can be written as $p^TAp=0$ with $A$ a symmetric $7\times7$ matrix in your case. So you have to choose $$7+6+\cdots+1=\sum_{i=1}^7i=\frac{7\cdot 8}2=\binom{6+2}2=28$$ numbers to write down that matrix. But multiples of that matrix represent the same hypersurface, so one degree of freedom is without geometric relevance, which accounts for the $-1$ in your formula. It is correct. I'm not exactly sure (yet) how to tacke the second part of your question, thus I'll leave this as a comment for now. If anyone writes an answer, feel free to include this verbatim or in your own words.